# Import Part of CSV to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, csv, datagridview

What I have is a CSV that I have imported into a Datagridview.

I am now looking for a way to only import the column with the header # and Delay and not all info in the CSV, so any help on this would be appreciated.

Here is the Code I have thus far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        String Fname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        //String Sname = "export";
        string[] raw_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Fname);
        string[] data_col = null;
        int x = 0;

        foreach (string text_line in raw_text)
        {
            data_col = text_line.Split(';');
            if (x == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < data_col.Count(); i++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                }
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(data_col);
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just replace the `for` loop over all fields by picking the index of the desired columns (or just hard-code the column names and skip the first line). Do the same for adding the row.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am really new to programming. Could you possibly give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: While the answer provided by @Ortund can give you a general idea, consider looking into [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) - it offers great support for handling CSV data.

Comment: Hi Filburt, I have had a look at the TextFieldParser and have no idea how to apply it to get the information into the data table.

Comment: My suggestion for TextFieldParser is targeted to cover handling the CSV input in a less brittle way rather than the insertion into the DGV - that should be covered by existing answer.

Comment: Hi Everyone, Thank you for all the help, but a a real newby, I have gone from bad to worse and cannot get this simple thing to work. If anyone has the heart could you please give me the code to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TextFieldParser can make handling CVS input less brittle:

```
// add this using statement for TextFieldParser - needs reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
...

// TextFieldParser implements IDisposable so you can let a using block take care of opening and closing
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(Fname))
{
    // configure your parser to your needs
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { ";" };
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false; // no messy code if your data comes with quotes: ...;"text value";"another";...

    // read the first line with your headers
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

    // add the desired headers with the desired data type
    dt.Columns.Add(fields[2], typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(fields[4], typeof(string));

    // read the rest of the lines from your file
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        // all fields from one line
        string[] line = parser.ReadFields();

        // create a new row <-- this is missing in your code
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

        // put data values; cast if needed - this example uses string type columns
        row[0] = line[2];
        row[1] = line[4];

        // add the newly created and filled row
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

// asign to DGV
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Filburt I have another question I would really appreciate your help on please

Answer (score 1):

When I read from CSV files, I create a list of values that I want for each row and use that list as the basis for my `INSERT` statement to the database.

I know where to find the data I want in the CSV file so I specifically target those items while I'm building my list of parameters for the query.

See the code below:

```
// Read the file content from the function parameter.
string content = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

// Split the content into an array where each array item is a line for
// each row of data.
// The Replace simply removes the CarriageReturn LineFeed characters from
// the source text and replaces them with a Pipe character (`|`)
// and then does the split from that character.
// This is just personal preference to do it this way
string[] data = content.Replace("\r\n", "|").Split('|');

// Loop through each row and extract the data you want.
// Note that each value is in a fixed position in the row.
foreach (string row in data)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
    {
        string[] cols = row.Split(';');

        List<MySqlParameter> args = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        args.Add(new MySqlParameter("@sid", Session["storeid"]));
        args.Add(new MySqlParameter("@name", cols[0]));
        args.Add(new MySqlParameter("@con", cols[3]));

        try
        {
            // Insert the data to the database.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Report an error.
        }
    }
}
```

In the same way, you could build your list/dataset/whatever as a data source for your datagridview. I would build a table.

Here's a mockup (I haven't got time to test it right now but it should get you on the right track).

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("#");
table.Columns.Add("Delay");

foreach (var line in raw_text)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row[0] = line[0]; // The # value you want.
    row[1] = line[1]; // The Delay value you want.

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

DataGridView1.DataSource = table;
DataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You may want to either explain that `Replace("\r\n", "|")` or omit it - since the OP didn't mention any issues splitting lines it will be rather confusing than clarifying for a stated newbie.

Comment: Thanks. I have not gotten it to work yet, but will keep trying till I do. I will ask again if I get really stuck.